# Programming language for sound manipulation

Tags: audio, frequency-spectrum, frequency, spectrogram

Having had little experience in PHP, I moved to C++ in-order to create a spectrogram, I wanted to create probably the simplest/easiest one for my first project, so easy infact I don't need reading/write to files or add settings to it.

But, as far as I have been learning C++ I was able to manipulate audio file, only to read and write, but the spectrogram works, by reading from a mic and this seems kind of hard to do. I have looked every link in Google, with the word spectogram and C++ in it, but I haven't gotten any useful page.

Now, if I am not mistaken, for the project I am working on, it may be good idea to use JAVA, because I read somewhere that JAVA is better than C++  `1` in a way it manipulates sound, and `2` it is actually easier to learn than C++

So, I wanted to ask here, if JAVA is better for my project, which I will be doing in Windows7?

Comment: This question is better off on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @JasonR I know. I asked it there, and they told me to ask it it. I got even 9 downvotes there.

Comment: The downvotes are likely because it's not a well-formed question. There is nothing about Java or C++ that makes one better-suited for audio manipulation. If you want to generate a plot, you're probably going to want an existing library of some kind. These exist for many languages, including C++ and Java. With that said, this isn't really related to signal processing, so I'm guessing this question will be closed also.

Comment: @user2487996 The question itself is off-topic here, but here's a link to C++ source for a spectrogram viewer: http://www.relisoft.com/freeware/freq.html

Answer (score 6):

For the first few experiments I would recommend using a scripting language like [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.de/products/matlab/) or [Python](http://www.python.org/). They're much easier to understand and much quicker to write than "lower level programming languages" like C++.

Matlab has a [signal processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.de/products/signal/) and can [read and write audio files](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html), do windowing, FFTs etc. as well as a very simple playback mechanism. Basic 2D and 3D-plotting tools are also built right into the language itself.

For Python there is the [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) library that does all kinds of scientific computing, including wavefile handling, windowing and FFT as well. Plus, there is the [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) that does all of the plotting for you.

In C++, you would have to find a UI toolkit that works for your OS, write a drawing widget to plot stuff in and then fill it with data. Plus, obviously all the memory management; wich will probably become the biggest annoyance and time-sink if you're not experienced in doing it.

To implement live playback and recording I suggest using [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/), a library written in C. There exists a Matlab .MEX utiliy called [PlayRec](http://www.playrec.co.uk/) and there are Python bindings called [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

From my experience, if you want to use portaudio I'd suggest using Python. Compiling the .mex utility is a huge pain while Python seemed to "just work".

If you manage to get it to work but still want to do it in C++ you can then port the codebase (just a couple of lines in both Matlab or Python) while still using portaudio for the audio input/output.

For a superficial comparison of the different code-complexities you can take a look at some work I wrote last year. Each implementation does the same thing, just in a different language:

- [FTM filter written in C/CUDA (plus some benchmarking stuff)](https://github.com/nils-werner/ftm-cuda)
- [FTM filter written in Matlab (plus some plotting stuff)](https://github.com/nils-werner/ftm-matlab)
- [FTM filter written in Python (just the filter, no extras)](https://github.com/nils-werner/ftm-python)

Comment: Thank for the answer. I was learning C++ for 4 days straight, but changed to Java because, C++ is actually harder with memory management and stuff, so I was looking for an answer which would allow me to choose between the two. whichever is the best.  So, do you think I can get the job done easier in python than in java?

Comment: Without having tried to do this kind of work in Java I would still say so, yes. Scipy and Numpy are a really stable and well designed foundation to do any kind of scientific computations with.